# Copying date from one table to another and change format in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to copy a date (Y-m-d) from one database table to another database table with format (Y-m-d H:i:s), with the following code:

```
<?php
  $host = "host";
  $user = "user";
  $password = "pass";
  $database1 = "home";
  $database2 = "teste";

  $con1 = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database1);
  mysqli_set_charset($con1, 'utf8');
  if (!$con1) {die(mysqli_connect_error($con1));}

  $select = "SELECT * FROM table1";
  $result = mysqli_query($con1, $select) or die(mysqli_error($con1));

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $id_product = $row[prod_id];
    $date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', '$row[date]');
    $date_add = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $con2 = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database2);
    mysqli_set_charset($con2, 'utf8');
    if (!$con2) {die(mysqli_connect_error($con2));}

    $ins = "INSERT INTO `table2` (id_product, date_add) VALUES ('$id_product',$date_add)";
    $mysq = mysqli_query($con2, $ins) or die(mysqli_error($con2));
  }
?>
```

This "INSERT" code is not working because on the table2 the date added is "0000-00-00 00:00:00" and I am sure that the date on table1 is, for example, 2017-02-13.
Is possible to check where is my code wrong?
I have checked other questions almost same problem and follow them but my result never worked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, your code has several issues. A decent IDE would show that to you in the editor.

### Code Issues

```
mysqli_set_charset($con1, 'utf8');
```

You are trying to set the charset using the connection, before you make sure that the connection was established.

```
if (!$con1)
{
    die(mysqli_connect_error($con1));
}
```

`mysqli_connect_error()` does not take any parameter, `$con1` is `false` anyway.

```
    $id_product = $row[prod_id];
```

There is no constant `prod_id`. You mean `$id_product = $row['prod_id'];` instead.

```
    $date       = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', '$row[date]');
```

You are trying to generate a date from the literal string `'$row[date]'` and not from the date you got from the database, which is `$row['date']`.

```
    $con2 = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database2);
```

You are creating a new database connection for each single record, without closing it after use.

```
    $ins = "INSERT INTO `table2` (id_product, date_add) VALUES ('$id_product',$date_add)";
```

`$date_add` is a string, it needs to be quoted.

### Your Problem

If you are using the correct types in your database tables, MySQL will add `00:00:00` automatically to the date, so you don't need to address that directly, as already stated by Gordon Linoff.

If that's not the case, the date still is transferred as a string, so simple string concatenation solves the problem.

```
$date_add = $row['date'] . ' 00:00:00';
```

### The Refactored Code

After the proposed cleanup, your code looks like this (and do what you want):

```
<?php
$host      = "host";
$user      = "user";
$password  = "pass";
$database1 = "home";
$database2 = "teste";

$source = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database1) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_set_charset($source, 'utf8');

$target = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database2) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_set_charset($target, 'utf8');

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = mysqli_query($source, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($source));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $id   = $row['prod_id'];
    $date = $row['date'] . ' 00:00:00';
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO `table2` (id_product, date_add) VALUES ('$id','$date')";
    mysqli_query($target, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($target));
}

mysqli_close($target);
mysqli_close($source);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (id_product, date_add)
    SELECT prod_id, date
    FROM table1;
```

If `date` is a `date` data type and `date_add` is `datetime`, then the time portion will be added and set to midnight automatically.